# Playing sound files with Java - Error: Could not find or load main class [Classname]

Tags: java, audio, javafx, playback

I'm trying to (do something as 'simple' as) getting java to play a sound file.
I've got the following java-code for it:

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class HelloWorldSound

{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String soundFile = "sound.mp3";
        Media hit = new Media(soundFile);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

(Sound file is in the same directory as the .java and .class file)

I compile it using:

```
    javac -cp jfxrt.jar HelloWorldSound
```

(The .jar file is in the same folder)

No errors on compilation, but when i try to run it with:

```
    java -cp jfxrt.jar HelloWorldSound
```

I get the follwing error:

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldSound
```

I'm running java version "1.7.0_45"

Any help on where i made my mistake(s)?

**The overall idea: The program is for a project, where input from an arduino will decide which sound to play and how often it should be repeated. If there is a better way to playback sound, please let me know** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it like this:

```
java -cp jfxrt.jar HelloWorldSound
```

then the only thing that is in your classpath is `jfxrt.jar`. If your class `HelloWorldSound` is not in a package and your have `HelloWorldSound.class` in your current directory, then you need to put the current directory in the classpath too:

```
java -cp jfxrt.jar;. HelloWorldSound
```

Note: `.` indicates the current directory.